# Можно ли с сайта определить что клиент зашел с виртуальной машины?

Tags: виртуальная-машина

Существуют ли способы определить, что посетитель сайта зашел с VMware или VirtualBox и пометить его как "неблагонадежного"?

Comment: Даже если и существуют, "неблагонадёжный" определённо потрудится замаскировать их, так что нет.

Comment: а какую деятельность вы так хотите определить?

Comment: Дело в технологии а не в ситуации. В силах ли фингерпринтинг чекать виртуальную машину или нет =)

Comment: нет, не в силах. зачастую сам софт находящийся на виртуальной машине не может определить что он на виртуалке. А если это просто посетитель сайта, то у вас есть только его UserAgent, а в нем нет места для такой информации, даже если бы браузер мог об этом знать. Это не говоря о том, что 90% "неблагонадежных" программ подменяют UserAgent и любой "фингерпринтинг" против них бесполезен по определению, вне зависимости на виртуалке они или нет

Answer (score 1):

<sub>СПОСОБ ПРЕДНОЗНАЧЕН ДЛЯ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЕЙ VIRTUALBOX. (хотя может это и рабочий способ для VMWare)</sub>

Можно определить пользователя, который находится на виртуальной машине через WebGL т.к. у пользователя на виртуальной машине обработчик (тот что рендерит саму картинку на экране) отличный от оригинального обработчика на хостовой машине. Соответственно, можно узнать использует ли пользователь виртуальную машину или нет. Вот, допустим как можно получить обработчика используя JavaScript:

```js
// сп*****о отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49267844/17799125
function getRenderer() {
  try {
    const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl')

    return gl.getParameter(gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info').UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL)
  } catch (_) {
    return 'N/A'
  }
}

console.log(getRenderer())
```

Способы обхода такого метода:

1. Tor Браузер - тор браузер заменяет название обработчика и вендора на сгенерированные им.
2. Расширение Браузера - есть расширения для браузера для подмены названия вендора и обработчика, к тому же, могут использоваться настоящие вендоры и обработчики, что усложнит идентификацию.
3. Блокировка через настройки - В Firefox и Chrome можно отключить WebGL к фигам собачьим в конфигурации. Минус данного способа в том, что вы лишаетесь возможности использовать WebGL в целом. Инструкция для Firefox:

- Заходим в **about:config**
- Пишем в поиске: *webgl.disabled*
- И переключаем у этого значения с **false** на **true**

[Инструкция для Chrome](https://techdows.com/2011/05/how-to-disable-webgl-in-chrome.html):

- Нажимаем на ярлык Chrome-а правой кнопкой мыши
- Нажимаем на "Свойства"
- Далее в поле "Объект", после `chrome.exe` добавляем  `--disable-3d-apis`
- Далее нажимаем "ОК"